# Write exactly N raw binary bytes to a file in C

Tags: c

I am writing some software that corrupts files. It stores the file in a buffer, corrupts that buffer by xoring it with random masks, then writes the modified buffer to stdout so that the (linux) user can pipe it to somewhere.

I have opened stdout in binary mode:

```
FILE *const out = fdopen(dup(fileno(stdout)), "wb");
```

But how do I actually write the whole buffer to `out` in one go?

It seems I have 2 options:

1. Iterate all bytes and do `fputc`
2. Hope that there are no nullbytes in the data and do `fputs`

I'm looking for a `fputb` which takes:

- A pointer to the data to be written
- A file descriptor to write it to
- The amount of bytes to write

(with better performance than a `fputc`-loop)

Comment: Spend an our every day reading the descriptions for the stdlibrary functions. Do that for a week or so. After that you would at least remember that they exist (and maybe even their names). Also: in the Unix man-pages, there is a section "see also", with related functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream )`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/):

> Writes an array of `count` elements, each one with a size of `size` bytes, from the block of memory pointed by `ptr` to the current position in the `stream`.